# SQL: Entity belongs (many-to-one) one of two different entities

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-schema

Let's say I have `organization` and `person` and they have a `one-to-many` relationship with `post`.

`post` could only be owned by either an organization or user (person).

What I'm doing right now is making the foreign key nullable and adding a `check constraint` to ensure only one of `organization_id` and `person_id` has a value and the other one is `null`.

Is this considered a valid `SQL` design (best practise)? What if I had more than two entities that could be the owner of a certain post?

[image]

Comment: You could combine the Organization and Person tables into one table.  You could also have one foreign key in your Post table and an indicator letting you know which table, either Organization or Person, is the parent.  The indicator can be a number or a code.  You would have to SELECT the Post rows and use the indicator to determine which parent table to SELECT from.

Comment: I suggest the first option offered by @GilbertLeBlanc, setup a `post_owner` table that has one-to-many relationship to `post`. This will make JOINs easy and efficient. Then you can have a `post_owner_type` field to indicate whether owner is an organization or a person or anything else, put an index on it for quick queries.

Comment: This is a common Question.  The answers are somewhat messy and usually indicate the need to rethink the schema.